# redirectToRoute does not work

Tags: php, symfony

I have an newAction and after saved the Product, I wont zu return in search page. after submit save buton I return to search page, but URL is still from newAction

```
 if($newForm->isSubmitted()&& $newForm->isValid()){
        if($newForm->get('submit')->isClicked()) {
          //Here comes CODE
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'saccess',
                'Product saved successfully'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute("product_seach");
        }
    }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo `product_seach` instead of `product_search` I guess.

What's your SF version ? 2.what.what ?

In your console, try `php app/console debug:router | grep product_search` and tell us if it can find your route.